# Прерывание ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax

При клике на кнопку просиходит вызов функции, в которой происходит вызов ajax запроса и его выполнение. Есть другая кнопка которая по идее должна сбрасывать этот запрос и все что происходит в нем в случае успеха/неудачи.

```
let xhr;
$(document).on('click', '.object-item', function (e) {
    constructAppartmentModal($(e.target).closest('.object-item').attr('data-id-apartment'));    
});

function constructAppartmentModal(id) {
    destructAppartmentModal();
    dataRequest = {
    idAppartment: id
};
dataRequest = JSON.stringify(dataRequest);
dataAjax = {
    action: 'wp_construct_appartment',
    dataRequest: dataRequest
}
xhr = $.get(ajax_object.ajax_url, dataAjax).then((response) => {
    // success
}, (response) => {
    //  error
});

$('body').on('click', '.close', function() {
    xhr.abort();
})
```

Данный код не рабочий, каким образом возможно сделать прерывание?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вашего кода - в том, что метод then возвращает обычное обещание (Promise), а не объект XHR.

Вот так будет правильнее:

```
xhr = $.get(ajax_object.ajax_url, dataAjax);
xhr.then((response) => {
    // success
}, (response) => {
    //  error
});
```